# Token for Rest API calls to Realtime Database giving "Unauthorized Request"

Tags: node.js, firebase, service-accounts

The following code is supposed to be creating an auth token from a serviceAccount that I generated within the Firebase console. However, making the Rest call that is in the code, the response that I get is "Unathorized request".

The `actions.json` endpoint that I'm trying to query doesn't even have a Security Rule preventing reading, it's got `.read: true`, so without an auth bearer, this request works, but with one, it fails..

```
const serviceAccountKey = {
  "type": "service_account",
  // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccountKey),
  databaseURL: 'https://firebase-project-id.firebaseio.com',
});

try {
  // Generate a custom authToken (Custom Token)
  const uid = 'luke'; // Unique identifier for the user
  const customAuthToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);

  const result = await fetch('https://firebase-project-id.firebaseio.com/action.json', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${customAuthToken}`
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())

  response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(result));
} catch (error) {
  response.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

I have checked the settings in IAM in the Cloud Console and made sure that the account associated with my Firebase instance has Realtime Database admin role (to ensure the serviceAccount that I'm generating the auth token from actually has the correct permissions):

[image]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.. The documentation indicates this should be much easier..

Answer (score 0):

The bearer header can only accept OAuth2 tokens of collaborators on the project. It can not be used to pass the ID token of a Firebase Authentication user in the project.

If you want to pass an ID token, pass it in the `auth` parameter to the request as shown in the documentation on [authenticating REST requests with an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token).

Comment: Thank you Frank.. That at least allows the read to work, however that isn't surprising because the security field says reading is allowed. If I try to write data to the database, I''m getting permission denied.. I don't understand and can't follow the Firebase docs to figure out how to get a token that will allow me to bypass security rules..

Comment: The problem is not the token, but how you pass it. If you want to pass the OAuth2 token for a collaborator on the project, you have to pass it in the `auth` parameter of the URL. --- If this remains problematic, consider using the Admin SDK for Realtime Database itself rather than the REST API, as this SDK will use your administrative credentials from `serviceAccountKey` automatically.

Comment: Thanks Frank. The problem with using the Admin SDK is that I want to make updates to my Realtime Database from a runtime like Deno Deploy or Cloudflare Workers, and the way that Firebase SDK is set up, it doesn't work